# React npm start doesn`t work on remote server. Port issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, centos, port

When I start to react app I don't receive anything from `http://example.com:58000`.

```
pacakge.json
     "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=58000 webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "starts": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

webpack

```
devServer: {
        host: "example.com",
        port:58000  

    },
```

What else I need to configure to make nmp start work the server is centos 7?

Answer (score 0):

The URL in your question needs one more zero. Is that the problem or did you typo in the question?